# How can I stop getting notifications about people I don't follow posting statuses on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

These notifications keep popping up, they're people I don't interact with, I've not spoken to number 2 or 3 in several years!

I've turned off everything I can find in the notification settings but it doesn't seem like these are able to be turned off?

[image: A screenshot of unwanted facebook notificaitions]

I'm following these people, but I don't have "Get notifications" ticked for any of them.

Answer (score 4):

Click the menu (indicated by three horizontal dots). You'll get at least two options: hide that individual notification and hide all about that person. Select the second and you should stop seeing the notifications.

[image: notifications with action menu]

Comment: I don't get the second option, the only one I have is "Hide this notification"

Comment: Are you friends with them? Are you following them? Otherwise, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes I'm following them, but "Get notifications" isn't ticked, and it's only random friends, different ones each time.

Comment: Then I guess I'm baffled. Maybe Facebook doesn't want you to have an empty notifications pane.

Comment: In any event, that's all important information that should be in your question.